# Separate 1 row data to multiple rows

Tags: sql, excel, pentaho

I currently have a table that contains multiple rows and columns like bellow (the data in the row is somewhat grouped)

```
ID Column1_1 Column1_2 Column1_3 Column1_4 Column2_1 Column2_2 Column2_3 etc.
1     data11    data12    data13   etc.
2     data21    data22    etc. 
3     data31     etc.
```

I need this table to be exported in an excel that looks like this:

```
ID  Column       DATA
1   Column1_1     data11
1   Column1_2     data12
1   Column1_3     data13
1   Column1_4     data14
2   Column2_1     data21
2   Column2_2     data22
```

I was thinking to export it in a big excel first and then create multiple sheets. But can I use group by in excel?

Comment: I just googled and founf this.try this https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2007/sorting-grouping-and-filtering-cells/1/

Comment: Why don't you first unpivot the data in the Database? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 with SSMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT
  ID, ColumnName, DataValue
FROM
  YourTable
UNPIVOT
(
  DataValue FOR ColumnName IN (Column1_1, Column1_2, Column1_3, Column1_4, Column2_1, Column2_2, Column2_3.........)
)
  AS unpvt;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot

Answer (score 0):

You are normalizing the data and you have a field just for it called `Row Normalizer`. ([Official doc is here](https://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Row+Normaliser)).

Admittedly, the first few times you pull your hair with an outdated vocabulary, just because Microsoft re-invented the wheel by calling this operation a 'pivot'.

In your case the `Typefield` is "Column", the `Fieldname` are the "Column1_1"s or whatever the column are named in your input, the `Type` is "Column1_1" or whatever you want to write in the column named `Column` on your output, and `New field` is "DATA" or whatever you want to name the output denormalized column.

Of course, there is a bottom button to help you, however, as it seams to be your first time, I suggest you try manually with two or tree column before.